# How to link missing pod headers - Xcode 11.2.1

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, bugsnag, xcode11

I'm killing myself over trying to get a Pod linked & the project up and running.  For some background: I am running a ReactNative (version `0.61.5`) project and am using Xcode `11.2.1`; the current cocoapods version is `1.9.1`.  It should also be noted that I am no iOS+Xcode expert.

The problematic package here is `@bugsnag/react-native`; specifically, the problem lies with the underlying native library, `bugsnag-cocoa`.  When building the project, I am getting the following error:

[image: Swift Compiler Error: No such module 'Bugsnag]

While the Pod is installed, it looks like the public headers aren't being linked correctly.

[image: Pod available in Pods project]

I do not see anything that jumps out as a bug in `@bugsnag/react-native`'s podspec file (https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-js/blob/next/packages/react-native/BugsnagReactNative.podspec).  The weird thing is, when I spin up a clean `react-native` project, and install `@bugsnag/react-native`, I don't run into issues--the pod is linked correctly and the project runs.

I tried adding the vendor lib, `bugsnag-cocoa`, to my project workspace; then proceeded to move the Bugsnag framework to my `Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content`--this worked locally, however, breaks in CI/CD :sadface:

I also tried to add `bugsnag-cocoa` as a sub-library of my project; however, I cannot do anything with the library from that point ... I can't click on the lib?  Why is that?

[image: Bugsnag project icon is opaque & unclickable]

---

Is there anyway I can manually add the headers from the pod to my project?  I tried adding the path, to the pod's vendor files, in the proj target's `Build Settings -> Library Search Paths` and `Build Settings -> Header Search Paths`--this did not work, I am still getting no such module `Bugsnag`.  It's very possible I missed something fwiw.

P.S.
I have the `.xcworkspace` opened, so that isn't the issue and I made sure to run `pod install` (amongst other permutations such as `pod install --repo-update` and `pod update`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using swift. You should include `#import <Bugsnag/Bugsnag.h>` in your bridging header file. Once you do that you shouldn't need to import Bugsnag into your AppDelegate file as Bugsnag will already be available.

Comment: Definitely!  This was a huge oversight on my part.  I figured it out eventually, but didn't come back to the post to note.  Thanks for contributing @Div-dog !